How can I mount this plate on a Steel Beam?
As mentioned in the question, I am looking for a method to attach this mounting bracket to the flange of a steel beam that permits effortless removal and remounting without permanent fixation.


clamps with bolts or just bolts.

"Effortless"? Really?

Or a switchable mag-mount such as used on drills etc but without any use or loads who knows...

effortless removal and remounting of what, the plate, or something attached to the plate?

What loads must it withstand while mounted? How effortless do you consider those "command strips" for mounting things to a wall?

The load is 9 kg. The removal and remounting of the plate should be done in a manner that allows for a maximum of 5-10 minutes to remove or remount it. Maybe not entirely effortless, but the removal of the plate should definitely be user-friendly

The dimensions of the plate are 20x20cm
